# How to allow null values on foreign keys in MS SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server

How to allow null (empty) values on foreign key column in MS SQL Server 2012 and preserve referential integrity?
I created constraint on foreign key in child table. It prevents deleting primary key record in parent table and it is OK. But it does not allow me to add (insert) new record into child table, leaving foreign key column empty. I have a lot of those situation in my app, where I would like to have possibility to leave FK column empty, and still have Referential Integrity ON, at least for Deleting from parent table. How to implement that???

Comment: Just allow null value for the field of the FK

Comment: Make sure the foreign key column allows NULL and the value is NULL rather than an empty string. That will allow inserts without a related row in the referenced table.

Comment: Can you show the table DDL?  Null columns in a FK are to be expected.  @litelite has the proper response  you just need to allow nulls for that column.  my guess is the table DDL has it defined to not allow nulls.  Referential integrity on the FK just means the ID being used (if one is used) must exist in the parent table.  However if NULL is the value stored in the FK it should be fine.

Comment: Well, I have "Allow null" on table definition for FK column in child table and still can not insert new record into child table if I do not choose some value in this field (I choose from picklist)! Could it be because my Data Entry form put "empty" default value to this column when nothing chosen from picklist, which could be incorrect? Maybe forcing my Data Entry form to put "null" value in this field if nothing is chosen from picklist will solve the problem????

Comment: That would do. Empty string is not same as null. You should also check for ON DELETE part of your fk

Comment: >>>Could it be because my Data Entry form put "empty" default value to this column when nothing chosen from picklist, which could be incorrect? Maybe forcing my Data Entry form to put "null" value<<< If your parent table has this "empty" value it will not be a problem, but if it hasn't or add it to parent or insert null (without quotes)

Comment: It seems I solved the problem Thanks to everyone!!!

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `ON DELETE SET NULL`. That way you will be able to insert null values in that column. Also your field should allow NULLs

Answer (score 0):

null values are not empty values. An empty value may refer to something in another table but a null value cannot refer to anything because it signifies that there is nothing to refer to. So allowing null values will by no means preserve referential integrity.

Answer (score -8):

Why not use a dummy FK, like -100 for example?